# How do i change everything behind a certain point in a Jagged array?

Tags: c#

Say I have a jagged array, and position 2,3 is taken by int 3.  Every other spot is filled with int 0.  How would I fill all the positions behind 2,3 with a 4?

```
0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0

0 0 0 3 0 0

0 0 0 0 0
```

to this:

```
4 4 4 4 4 4

4 4 4 4

4 4 4 3 0 0

0 0 0 0 0
```

Ive tried variations of this:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;

for (int x = 0; x < a; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < board.space[b].Length; y++)
    {
           board.space[x][y] = 4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private static void ReplaceElements(int[][] array, int x, int y, int newValue)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= x && i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
        {
            if (j < y || i < x)
                array[i][j] = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
int[][] array = new int[4][];
array[0] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
array[1] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0};
array[2] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0};
array[3] = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int x = 2;
int y = 3;
int newValue = 4;

ReplaceElements(array, x, y, newValue);

foreach (int[] inner in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", inner));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have it check if the current element it is on is equal to 3. If it is, stop by altering some control variable, otherwise change the value to 4.

```
bool done = false;
for (int y = 0; y < board.Size && !done; ++y)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < board.space[y].Length && !done; ++y)
    {
        if (board.space[y][x] == 3) done = true;
        else board.space[y][x] = 4;
    }
}
```